# redirect traffic to 2 different URLs depening on variable in URL

Tags: php, redirect

I am very new to php, but ill try to explain as good as I can. I have a page where I want to send users to different URLs depending on variables in the traffic/ad url. First I have a URL for my traffic which is www.testing.com?adid=hello and then I have click links for each button on my landing page, here I want to put a script that sends them to URL x if adid=hello but if adid is empty or adid is not even present in the url (as it wont be for organic traffic) then send them to page y.

This is what I have now:

```
<?php
$adid= $_GET['adid'];

if($adid == 'hello'){
header("Location: http://www.x.com");

}else {
header("Location: http://www.y.com/");
}
?>
```

Im thinking the link on the button should be www.testing.com/redirect.php?adid={adid} but Im not getting any value for {adid} from the first link. Please help!

Comment: What is the URL that appears on the browser's address bar after you click on the button/link ?

Comment: if I access the button link redirect.php?adid={adid} I come to y.com. I want the value "hello" to be placed in {adid} as it was set in the first link, so it should take me to x.com but it doesnt. If I however put redirect.php?adid=hello then it takes me to x.com.

Comment: Can you add a snippet of the code for the button/links that you mentioned? The PHP snipped you have posted will work. The problem is around how you are defining the URL for the button/links.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, the code of the button/links is the one above (or below as I tested that one too). Again, I think the problem is the link im using on the buttons (now redirect.php?adid={adid}), it doesnt seem to pass the adid from first link to second link. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$adid = ""; // initialize variable with blank  value

if(isset($_GET['adid'])) // check if is send through get
{
    $adid= trim($_GET['adid']); // assign value to variable
}   

if($adid == 'hello'){
    header("Location: http://www.x.com");
    exit;
}else {
    header("Location: http://www.y.com/");
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: I added the code but still cant get to x.com. I first entered with link ?adid=hello and then entered with link redirect.php?adid={adid} but it doesnt seem like it fetches the value "hello" on the second link, it still takes me to y.com. So I basically need to know what URL to put on the button links. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yeah I dont think the problem is the code I think the problem is the URL I use on the button link, should it be only redirect.php or do I have to add the adid value like redirect.php?adid={adid} or anything similar? I cant add "hello" to all links as this would send all users to x.com.

Comment: Link on button is:

.../test.php?adid={adid}

The tracking software I use (voluum) just told me that you cant pass dynamic values in the click tracking link yet. Perhaps thats why this is not working.

Comment: I asked voluum and they responded this:

"ok, I understand now. So this is not possible at the moment (meaning passing variables to click link)

You could create your own tool, which would work something like this: The lander would redirect to your own site "www.xxx.com", which would use double meta refresh, which would redirect to an html with the voluum /click URL. Or you could use a 302 redirect from your site (www.xxx.com) to an html with the /click tracking link with the added voluum data (so /click?voluumdata).

This is something you could test, and might work."